# Are the OSX Mavericks tags visible from the command line?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, macos

For example, suppose I have a directory structure such as

```
/Users
    /tlehman
        /Math
            algebraic_varieties.tex [tagged: Math, Documentation]
            projective_geometry.pdf [tagged: Math]
        /Development
            visualize_surfaces.py   [tagged: Math, Programming]
            solve_polynomials.scm   [tagged: Math]
    /guest
        /Desktop
            welcome.rtf             [tagged: Documentation]
/Volumes
    /USBKey
        assignments_for_may.txt     [tagged: Math]
        using_LaTeX.pdf             [tagged: Documentation]
```

From the command line, is there a way I can use `ls` (or something like it) to display all the files tagged as "Math"?

EDIT: I made a tool called `tfind` that does this: https://github.com/tlehman/bin/blob/master/tfind

Comment: See https://github.com/jdberry/tag

Comment: I second the recommendation for `tag` by James Berry at `https://github.com/jdberry`.  You can install it via `brew install tag`, add a tag via `tag -a <tag> <file>`, find tags via `tag -f <tag1, tag2>`.  Very, very handy, I use it all the time.

Comment: Yes, definitely get the `tag` command. Installs via brew very easily.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming they will be an [xattr](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html) like they currently are on 10.8.3 (and older)

Currently, you can view which extended attributes a file has with `ls -l@`.

But to see the contents of the attributes, you have to use `xattr`.

Comment: You were right, the tags are stored as an xattr

Comment: FYI: With OS X El Capitan, I used the command, `xattr -pl com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags filename`.  However, it was not very friendly output.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can find files that have a given user tag using `mdfind`.

Create a file and assign it a a custom tag in Finder.

Then go in a terminal; you will find it with:

```
mdfind "kMDItemUserTags == Math || kMDItemUserTags == Programming"
```

or

```
mdfind "kMDItemUserTags == Math && kMDItemUserTags == Programming"
```

See also `-onlyin aFolder` to restrict the search.

I didn't check how complex these boolean expressions can be, but these two examples work.

You can pipe the output to `ls` like this:

```
mdfind "kMDItemUserTags == mathTag || kMDItemUserTags == anotherTag" \
| while read f; do ls "$f"; md5 "$f"; done
```

Also, mdfind has an option "-0"

```
    -0                Use NUL (``\0'') as a path separator, for use with xargs -0.
```

which can be practical with nasty filenames.

Comment: The problem with this method is that it doesn't find all the files, returning only a (possibly empty) sub-set of files.

Comment: It appears they've introduced a simplified `mdfind` syntax for tags, e.g.: `mdfind "tag:Math"`, `mdfind "tag:Math OR tag:Programming"`

Comment: @markvgti Which files does this command not find ?

Comment: @AntoineLecaille I have 295 files in a directory with the "Orange" tag (the Orange Label before upgrading to Mavericks). That command lists only 11 of them. Also have many files tagged "Green" --- that command finds none of them.

Comment: @wjv I used the syntax suggested by you and got exactly the same results as I listed above.

Comment: @markvgti Then take one Orange file that is found with this command and one that is not, and find the differences with xattr or mdls ?

Answer (score 4):

You can get all tags of a file with:

`mdls -name kMDItemUserTags filename`

Comment: This seems to be the inverse of what was asked. Your command dumps all tags for one file. I think the OP wants to know all files with one tag.

Comment: Still, useful.  It answers the question I had when I Googled and ended up here.  If there isn't a different Q/A that covers this it might be worth the effort to post and answer one yourself.